# Magento 2.3 - Sometimes 404 error when creating a shipment

Tags: magento2, shipping

sometimes when creating a shipment through the Magento 2 admin we get a 404 error. I have tried almost everything but the reason why is very vague and not consistent. I now found out that it's most likely due to caching, when I clear cache (Redis and normal) it works for a while, I hope somebody can help me with a solution.

[image]

Comment: I am on Magento 2.3.4 and I also have the same issue when I input the tracking number and submit the shipment.

Comment: I never found a solution :-(

Comment: Any solution on this???